# Why String.Split(regex) in java returns array of elements of size less then what actually is present?

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

The number of elements returned is less than what I'd expected when I run `String.split()`

**Example:-** The actual string is "country,12345,2,1,,1,,", so 8 elements were expected in array returned, but the size of array was "6"

### Code:-

```
String line1 = "country,12345,2,1,,1,,";
String data1[] = line1.split(",");      
System.out.println("Length : "+data1.length);
```

### Output:-

```
Length : 6
```

Why is it so?

Comment: try outputting each of the elements in the array to see what's inside?

Comment: What Java version are you using? I think this was changed with Java 8, because it always prints `8` for me.

Comment: @Aru I've just noticed, looking at the question again, that that precise sample code _will_ print 8 (because the last field is not empty - there's a space after the last comma), but the "example" above it doesn't have the trailing space, and with that value for `line1` you'd get 6.

Comment: Learn to always read JavaDoc of what you are using!

Answer (score 7):

Because the single-argument `split` method drops trailing empty fields.  If you want to preserve them use the two-argument version, with a negative `limit` parameter.

```
String data1[] = line1.split(",", -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Ian Roberts

`Split()` method drops tailing empty fields , so trailing empty fields won't count.

for better understanding , see code below -

Case 1:

```
String line1 = "country,12345,2,1,,1, ,";
String data1[] = line1.split(",");
System.out.println("Length : "+data1.length);

Output : 7
```

As second last character within comma is  i.e. something (but not empty) , split won't count last part only.

Case 2:

```
String line1 = "country,12345,2,1,,1,, ";
String data1[] = line1.split(",");
System.out.println("Length : "+data1.length);

Output : 8
```

As last character after comma is  i.e. something (but not empty) , split will count all parts.

Answer (score -2):

I think you have to change the regex:

String data1[] = line1.split("\\,");